# How to change textContent via javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a registration form page, and there is empty div i want to use to display errors. To check forms before triggering php script i use javascript:

```
function errorHandler(){
    var loginIn;
    var passIn;


    loginIn = document.forms["regForm"]["login"].value;
    passIn = document.forms["regForm"]["password"].value;

    if (loginIn == "" || loginIn == null) {
        alert("LOGIN CANNOT BE EMPTY");
        return false;
    } 
}
```

It works fine, and alert message do appear when i call them like this:

`<form  name="regForm" action= "save_user.php" onsubmit="return errorHandler()" method="post">`.

But there is as i mentioned before a div inside of the form:
 `div id ="errorArea"></div>` and when i try to put a text inside of this div like this:

```
function errorHandler(){

    var loginIn;
    var passIn;
    var erorAreaMessage;

    loginIn = document.forms["regForm"]["login"].value;
    passIn = document.forms["regForm"]["password"].value;
    erorAreaMessage = document.getElementById('errorArea').textContent;

    if (loginIn == "" || loginIn == null) {
        erorAreaMessage = "LOGIN CANNOT BE EMPTY";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Nothing happens, can someone explain me why?

Comment: Changing the `arorAreaMessage` variable doesn't automatically change the `textContent`. You need to actually assign to the `.textContent` property. `document.getElementById('errorArea').textContent = "LOGIN CA..."`

Comment: There is a stray closing curly brace (`}`) at the end of your code.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen: That's the closing brace for the `function errorHandler() {`

Comment: @cookiemonster Ah. I did not notice that. Never mind then.

Comment: @cookiemonster is there any way to force reload after message is shown?

Comment: Reload the page? Yes, but your changes to the page will be lost. Or did you want to only affect part of the page?

Comment: @cookiemonster like reload after period of time?

Comment: Yes, look into `setTimeout` to delay execution of code, and `window.location` to reload the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the value inside the `<div>`. That can done by setting the `innerHTML` or `textContent` property to your error-message.
Try this -

```
...
if (loginIn == "" || loginIn == null) {
    document.getElementById('errorArea').textContent = "LOGIN CANNOT BE EMPTY";
    return false;
}}
```

Comment: @Amal.A There is no problem with textContent.You needed to set it with the err message

Comment: If you simply get the textContent as you were in your code @Amal.A you're simply calling the getter for textContent. You need to invoke the setter by explicitly calling something like `element.textContent = "blah";`

Comment: You should not use innerHTML to do what the OP asked as you suggested for an option. It is a security risk especially when you are only passing plain text.

Comment: Can I set a number as textcontent? my node app with tsconfig and checkjs=true complains that type number cannot be assigned to textcontent. [Here](https://tik9.herokuapp.com/public/calculate.html) I use buttons which are created in a loop with iteration.